# Android Search Checkable ListView

Tags: android, listview, search

I want to make it so a user can search through a ListView checking desirable items. I have already created a checkable ListView without the search implementation. I have tried adding a search using an EditText and a TextChangedListener. This works fine for a normal ListView but since this method creates a new adapter every time the user types, the checked items are lost.

My questions:

A. Is there someway to search through a ListView while maintaing the same adapter?

B. Is there someway to use my current method of using TextChangedListener but maintain the items checked?

Comment: You should add some code to show how you build that checkable `ListView`.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does not have to do with the way the checkable ListView is built, my problem is that my current implementation of using a search creates a new adapter every time the user types, thus losing the data of which items are checked.

Comment: What is stopping you from saving the current state of the checked items in the `ListView` and re-applying it one you've built the new adapter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own class that consists of the listview elemnt's field and add one more field (isChecked). When you recreate adapter, you use already created objects and checked state is saved and in the getview of each row you can check\uncheck this item by this property

Here is my custom checkbox, you can use it and modify if you want, i think it can fit you purposes (i take this code as is from my app and you can check how it works in [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.human.notes)):

```
package ru.human.notification;


import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;

public class CustomCheckBox extends CheckedTextView
{

    private int CHECKED_IMAGE;
    private int UNCHECKED_IMAGE;
    private main_full parent;
    private ArrayList<View> viewsToCheck;
    private int msgType;

    public void setParent(main_full parent, int msgType)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.msgType = msgType;
        setOnLongClickListener(longClickListner);
    }


    public void addViewToCheck(View view)
    {
        this.viewsToCheck.add(view);
    }


    OnLongClickListener longClickListner = new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (parent != null && isChecked())
                parent.showTimeDialog(msgType);
            return true;
        }
    };

    OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!isChecked())
            {
                setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                setPaintFlags(0);
                setChecked(true);
                setCheckMarkDrawable(CHECKED_IMAGE);
                if (parent != null)
                    parent.showTimeDialog(msgType);
            }
            else
            {
                setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgrey));
                setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                setChecked(false);
                setCheckMarkDrawable(UNCHECKED_IMAGE);
            }
            for (View view: viewsToCheck)
                view.setVisibility(isChecked()?View.VISIBLE:View.GONE);
        }
    };

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setOnClickListener(listener);
        System.out.println("1");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        // TODO mmmm

    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        viewsToCheck = new ArrayList<View>();
        String xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/ru.human.notification";
        setOnClickListener(listener);       
        System.out.println("2");
        int k = R.drawable.alarmgrey;
        CHECKED_IMAGE = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(xmlns, "checkedImage", 404);
        UNCHECKED_IMAGE = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue(xmlns, "uncheckedImage", 404);
        setCheckMarkDrawable(UNCHECKED_IMAGE);
        setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgrey));
        setTextSize(18f);
        setPaintFlags(Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
//      setChecked(false);
        System.out.println(CHECKED_IMAGE +" " + UNCHECKED_IMAGE + " " +k);


        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        final Context parent = context;
        System.out.println("3");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        setOnClickListener(listener);
    }

}
```

attrs.xml:

```
</declare-styleable>


    <declare-styleable name="CustomCheckBox">
        <attr name="uncheckedImage" format="integer"/>
        <attr name="checkedImage" format="integer"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

usage:

```
<ru.human.notification.CustomCheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/delayed"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/settingsbutton"
                    android:checked="false"
                    customcheckbox:checkedImage="@drawable/clockcolor"
                    android:text="@string/delay"
                    customcheckbox:uncheckedImage="@drawable/clockgrey" />
```

Put this view to you listview and create setChecked method (code is the same like in onClick method). Don't pay attention on setParent and addViewToCheck method - they are ways to control UI in my app.

Comment: Great Suggestion! I rewrote by code to accomodate for this, but I am running into a problem, it seems that on a checkable listview you cannot set the check value from the getView() method. I will look further into this.

Comment: You can extend checkedTextView and build in your new view to the listView (check my edition)